# Check if any key from a list is present in Cassandra map column

Tags: cassandra

My table looks something like this:

```
create table dummy(
    solution_id text,
    some_id uuid,
    ts timestamp,
    temporal map<text, float>
    version int,
    data_name text,
    primary key(solution_id, data_name, some_id)
);
```

with a secondary index on keys of temporal

```
create index on dummy(KEYS(temporal))
```

I am able to do a query like:

```
select * from dummy where solution_id='something' and temporal contains key 'some_key'
```

What I want to do is check if the temporal contains any key from a list, is this possible in Cassandra? I can't include temporal in my primary_key because this is going to be a dynamic column and there would be other columns like it.

Comment: `SELECT * from dummy where solution_id='test' and temporal contains key 'test3' OR temporal contains key 'test1' ALLOW FILTERING`.. I don't know how efficient it will be or even it fits your use case.....      http://grokbase.com/t/cassandra/user/162aabm9c3/select-values-from-map-with-multiple-key-values-in-where-clause

Comment: This doesn't work, I had previously tried the solution in the link which also doesn't work.

Comment: the query in comment works for cassandra 3.0....

Comment: Cassandra CQL does not support such operations, but one can use dataframes to do such type of queries or even complex queries. Doing these queries with dataframes is kind of slow. Alternatively if you have spark in your infrastructure, you can use it to perform such queries with much lower latencies.